# Ruby, How to decrypt with only symmetric key

Tags: ruby, encryption

I refer to a golang example https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/09.6.html

whereby

```
ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext, key)
plaintext  = decrypt(ciphertext,key)
```

Now, I on my client side, for some reason, I am using golang code for encyrption.

On the server side, I am running Sinatra and wants to create a decrypt function of the similar, but after looking through most web examples, the decryption requires IV which on the client side is not able to set or supply.

How to I go about this?

Comment: What's "IV"? It's not clear what the question is.

Comment: @DaveNewton in cryptography, _IV_ usually refers to "initialization vector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the golang exampe you refer to:

> The Go language supports symmetric encryption algorithms in its crypto
>   package. Do not use anything except AES in **GCM mode** if you don't know
>   what you're doing!

**GCM mode** don't work without an **IV**. If you are going to use this sample code, you are going to need to adhere to the same mode on server side .. so you need to relate to the use of **IV**.

Comment: would u recommend a simple encryption that is both supported on both languages